# How to get rid of Visual Studio Test warning about "vstest.console.exe version does not support the /diag flag." in build on VSTS

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm not having any build warnings in the Visual Studio solution.

When running an automated build on VSTS which includes a "Visual Studio Test" task, which runs all unit tests, that task reports the warning:

```
##[warning]vstest.console.exe version does not support the /diag flag. Enable diagnostics via the exe.config files
```

This makes the mail sent to the coder that triggered the build look like
[image]

This is a problem because I don't want to tell the coders to ignore build warnings sent from the build server. So, how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my, it was as simple as changing the Build configuration variable system.debug from true to false.

[image]